Is there a way to embed hyperlinks inside a label containing mixed text?
I'm getting some text from an API that contains hyperlinks embedded in a string response. E.g.:
This text is coming from an API. Click http://www.example.com to visit us.

Text can contain one or more hyperlinks anywhere in this incoming text. For example, another API call can return something like this:
Call from http://www.example.com. Please visit us at http://www.test.org to see the possibilities.

I'm displaying it inside a Label. Is it possible to make inline links to dynamic text clickable in such a case and open the respective link in a WebView?
If not label then can a span be used to parse and construct incoming text with GestureRecognizers?

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/maui-samples/userinterface-hyperlinks/

@Jason Thanks Jason. But unfortunately, in my case, it is not compile time hyperlinking. Is there a way to add inline hyperlinks to dynamic data at runtime? I'm afraid examples from the page with FormattedString in XAML is not useful there.

You can parse the data and build the label dynamically

Thank you will try it. Also in such case, will it be possible to bind that parsed data to the label using a DataTemplate?


Is it possible to make links clickable in such a case and open the
respective link in a WebView?

Yes, and you can refer to the official doc: Create a reusable hyperlink class
Create a HyperlinkSpan class in the root directory of your project:
public class HyperlinkSpan : Span
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UrlProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Url), typeof(string), typeof(HyperlinkSpan), null);

    public string Url
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UrlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UrlProperty, value); }
    }

    public HyperlinkSpan()
    {
        TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
        TextColor = Colors.Blue;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            // Launcher.OpenAsync is provided by Essentials.
            Command = new Command(async () => await Launcher.OpenAsync(Url))
        });
    }
}

Add it to MainPage.xaml:
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp4"
             x:Class="MauiApp4.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        ...
        <Label>
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span Text="Alternatively, click " />
                    <local:HyperlinkSpan Text="here"
                                         Url="https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/" />
                    <Span Text=" to view .NET documentation." />
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

Here is the effect.

Yes, I'm aware of this for static text that you can hyperlink in xaml. In my case, it is dynamic data, where at runtime, I've to hyperlink based on data received from database.

It could be an overkill but here is a solution, to generate dynamically (at runtime) your spans based on the text returned by the api using regex for parsing:
  FormattedString ParseUrlsGenSpans(string text)
  {
      FormattedString formattedString = new FormattedString();
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
          return formattedString;

      int i = 0, prevStartIndex = 0;
      string pattern = @"\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S+\b";
      var regexRes = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

      var regexMatch = regexRes.Matches(text);

      if (regexMatch.Count == 0)
          return formattedString;

      foreach (Match match in regexMatch)
      {
          if (match.Index < prevStartIndex || match.Index == 0)
          {
              formattedString.Spans.Add(new HyperlinkSpan()
              {
                  Text = text.Substring(match.Index, match.Length),
                  Url = text.Substring(match.Index, match.Length)
              });
              formattedString.Spans.Add(new Span()
              {
                  Text = text.Substring(prevStartIndex, match.Index - prevStartIndex)
              });
          }
          else
          {
              formattedString.Spans.Add(item: new Span()
              {
                  Text = text.Substring(prevStartIndex, match.Index - prevStartIndex)
              });
              formattedString.Spans.Add(new HyperlinkSpan()
              {
                  Text = text.Substring(match.Index, match.Length),
                  Url = text.Substring(match.Index, match.Length)
              });
          }

          if (++i == regexMatch.Count)
          {
              formattedString.Spans.Add(item: new Span()
              {
                  Text = text.Substring(match.Index + match.Length)
              });
          }
          prevStartIndex = match.Index + match.Length;
      }
      return formattedString;
  }

You need to have a reference to your label or a way to update it, just for demo:
private void Label_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var label = (Label)sender;
    label.FormattedText = ParseUrlsGenSpans(
        @"Call from http://www.example.com. Please visit us at http://www.test.org to see the possibilities. http://www.test.org ");
}

HyperlinkSpan is defined in Create a reusable hyperlink class.

Have you got the chance to try my answer ? it answers your issue with dynamic data during the runtime
